# How can I get if an user has a notification using the facebook api graph?

Tags: java, android, facebook

Could someone please explain how can I implement that or if is posible?
I'm doing an android app that connects to facebook and then checks if the user has unseen notifications and shows a mesagge in the app if there is unseen notifications.

I couldn't figure out from the documentation. I tried using the **me/notifications** but it appears that is only for v.2.2 so I was wondering if there is another way.

Thanks!